# Python: Nessus API not Downloading Report

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I need help in downloading the report from Nessus API.
In the current scenario, the command is running fine but instead of downloading the report file in csv format, it is throwing all the output in the console.

How can I download and save the file instead of getting the output on the console?

```
import requests

url = "https://tenable.com/scans/<scan_id>/export/<file_id>/download"

headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-apikeys': "accessKey=key;secretKey=key"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: are you sure you need to set the header to `accept`: `application/json` ? it is advertising what the client will understand, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)

Answer (score 0):

save it to a file like this:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Agree that I can save the output like this. Is it not possible to directly download without sending the output to file.

Comment: what do you mean with "directly download"? to where?

Comment: what I mean, when I was going through Nessus API documentation. First, you need to define in which format you want to download file(csv, pdf, html) and then you need to download file using this API request. For PDF, I'm getting 500 error but for csv, I'm getting output in the console instead of csv file download without sending the output to a file.

Comment: it's not fully clear what you want to achieve. what is the difference between "csv file download" and "sending output to a file" when you think of code?

Comment: I want the above script to download files in whatever supported format I want. downloading using an API call will give my file a name and download the proper format file. But, when I have to write the console output to a file. I need to give some names and format to a file each time I want to download. I hope, you got my point, using UI it is working fine.

Comment: can you update your post with expected output / filename saved?